# Struts2 jQuery plugin - submit button

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, struts2, struts2-jquery

I have Struts 2 jQuery plugin submit button, when click the button its not firing the action class as Struts submit button. I need to keep the same page after click the button.Please look into below code difference.

**Struts submit button - Working good:**

```jsp
<s:form action="product!list" id="searchForm" theme="simple" method="Post">
     <s:submit action="product" method="list" value="Find" />
</s:form>
```

**Converting Struts submit to Struts-jQuery submit submit button - Not Working good:**

```jsp
<s:form action="product!list" id="searchForm" theme="simple" method="Post" >     
     <sj:submit />
</s:form>
```

if using only form action `<sj:submit/>` , the page the refreshing and working as Struts tag, but it should not be.

Comment: Define "not working good". What's in your JS console? What's in the DEBUG-level devMode=true server logs? What if you just use the form's action instead of setting href?

Comment: <sj:submit /> page is refereshing  , but it should ot happen , because its ajax supported.I need to submit the page with out page refresh .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order `<sj:submit>` to work properly `targets` attribute must be set to some value and form must have `id` attribute.

```
<s:form action="product!list" id="searchForm">     
  <sj:submit targets="results"/>
</s:form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should include `<sj:head/>` tag in the body of the `<head>`. This tag links JQuery and `stylesheet` on the page and other initial things, without it Ajax call has not made and as a result page refreshes. See examples of submitting tag [`<sj:submit>`](https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-jquery/wiki/SubmitTag):

> ```xml
> <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
> <%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
> <html>
>   <head>
>     <sj:head/>
>   </head>
>   <body>
>     <s:form id="form" action="AjaxTest">
>       <input type="textbox" name="data">
>       <sj:submit value="Submit Form" />
>     </s:form>
>   </body>
> </html>
> ```